# stop overriding scrapy settings.py

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm using subprocess to run several scrapy spiders in parallel like this:

```
processes = [Popen(['scrapy', 'crawl', 'myspider', '-a', 'custom_argument={}'.format(argument)]) \
             for argument in custom_arguments]

while processes:
    for p in processes[:]:
        if p.poll() is not None:
            processes.remove(p)
```

To enter custom arguments into each spider via subprocess my spider starts like this:

```
class myspider(scrapy.Spider):
    
    name = 'myspider'

    def __init__(self, custom_argument=None, *args, **kwargs):    
        super(myspider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...
    
    def start_requests(self):
        ...
```

This seems to work fine except the settings I chose in `settings.py` get overridden:

```
2021-01-06 16:57:16 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': 'True', 'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY': '0.5', 'BOT_NAME': 'openrent', 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False, 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'openrent.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['openrent.spiders'], 'USER_AGENT': 'Safari/537.36'}
```

How do I stop original settings getting overridden like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error

This log line means that settings from scrapy [default settings](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/2.4.1/scrapy/settings/default_settings.py) was replaced by
settings defined in `settings.py` file from your project.

| setting name | scrapy default settings value | your `settings.py` value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED` | `False` | `True` |
| `AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY` | `5.0` | `0.5` |
| `BOT_NAME` | `scrapybot` | `openrent` |
| `COOKIES_ENABLED` | `True` | `False` |
| `NEWSPIDER_MODULE` | `` | `openrent.spiders` |
| `SPIDER_MODULES` | `[]` | `['openrent.spiders']` |
| `USER_AGENT` | `Scrapy/2.4 (+https://scrapy.org)` | `Safari/537.36` |

Without `NEWSPIDER_MODULE` and `SPIDER_MODULES` settings defined in your `settings.py` scrapy will be unable to read your spider class.

Comment: Ah I see I've completely misread the log output -- it means default settings have been overridden by the ones in settings.py, not that the ones in settings.py have been overriden!